# Filter or analyzer to equate English numbers and arabic numerals

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm running an Elasticsearch server.

I'd like a query such as `fifty two meters` to match a document containing `52 meters`.

Is there any plugin (filter or analyzer) that converts number words to arabic numerals?

Comment: You could try to use a [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) to equate all spelled out number with their numeric equivalent.

Comment: @Val, true, but it would get very long.  For example, I would have to specify the synonym `"seven hundred and twenty six => 726"`.  I was hoping for some programmatic solution wrapped up into an ES plugin, similar to PyPI's [num2words](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words).

Comment: There are  a few projects out there that do this in Java ([one here](https://github.com/gulimran/num2words)), so creating a token filter that leverages it wouldn't be too difficult in my opinion. I'll try to get to it over lunch if I have time :-)

Comment: Obviously, I didn't get the time to finish this plugin in time. I'll update this thread when done.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no plug-in for elasticsearch to convert words to number.

I suggest you to create a code that gets raw query as  an input and outputs the transformed the query (i.e: convert words to number) for elasticsearch.

You can use [this ruby gem (open-source)](https://github.com/markburns/numbers_in_words) to convert words to number and vice versa.

> ```
> NumbersInWords.in_numbers("nineteen sixty five")
> 1965
> ```

And to make things easier [ruby intergration for elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby) can used to finally query the elasticsearch and get the results.

```
require 'elasticsearch'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true

client.transport.reload_connections!

client.cluster.health

client.search q: 'test'
```